# How to restore nuget packages without visual studio?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

Is there a way to automatically restore NuGet packages of a solution without using Visual Studio (i.e. using the NuGet command line)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the nuget.exe (which you can download from [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)).
And than execute

```
nuget restore packages.config
```

The full documentation of the nuget.exe is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
You can use NuGet command line the follwing will install the packages for a solution

> Update-Package

This will update all the packages for a project

> Update-Package -ProjectName MyProject

If you need more options please have a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages)

Comment: My understanding is that this is cmdlet that is executed from within visual studio?